# Changing the dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a numpy array `X` with shape `(5600,)` and the contents of the array has shape `(Y,1024)` where `Y` varies.

Like `X.shape = (5600,)` and `X[0].shape = (28,1024)` `X[1].shape = (17,1024)`  and so on.

I want to stack all the elements one over each other so that the shape become like `(5600,Y,1024)`

How can I do that?

Comment: You need a fixed value for `Y` in order for `(5600, Y, 1024)` to be a valid shape.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Can I just stack the elements one over other?

Comment: Yes, but in that case, you will get a 2D array `(X, 1024)` where `X = 28 + 17 + ...` in your example.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Thank you